# How to get password from a credentials parameter in Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job, and it has a Credentials Parameter of the type "Username with password". Let's call this Credentials Parameter `DB_USER_CRED`.

Now, I have 2 credentials of type "Username with password" stored on Jenkins already, call them `DB_USER1` and `DB_USER2`.  Hence, I have this in my job:

```
withCredentials([
            usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'DB_USER1', usernameVariable: 'DB_USER1_NAME', passwordVariable: 'DB_USER1_PASSWORD'),
            usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'DB_USER2', usernameVariable: 'DB_USER2_NAME', passwordVariable: 'DB_USER2_PASSWORD')
            ]){
```

So when a user runs the job, he/she can choose either `DB_USER1` or `DB_USER2` to fill in the parameter `DB_USER_CRED` with.  And then I can tell which user was used by checking `$DB_USER_CRED`.  But then is there a way to get the password from `DB_USER_CRED`?  I'd like not to have to compare `$DB_USER_CRED` against `$DB_USER1_NAME` and `$DB_USER2_NAME` in order to find out which password to use, i.e., `$DB_USER1_PASSWORD` or `$DB_USER2_PASSWORD`. The reason being there might be 10 possible DB users that have access to this job and it is not realistic to have to compare `$DB_USER_CRED` to all of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204897020-Fetch-a-userid-and-password-from-a-Credential-object-in-a-Pipeline-job-

So to use the example from above, the solution is:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: env.DB_USER_CRED, usernameVariable: 'DB_USER_CRED_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DB_USER_CRED_PASSWORD']])
{
// The password is $DB_USER_CRED_PASSWORD
}
```

My job also uses other credentials stored in Jenkins, and they can be appended this way:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: env.DB_USER_CRED, usernameVariable: 'DB_USER_CRED_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DB_USER_CRED_PASSWORD'],
usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'OTHER_CRED', usernameVariable: 'OTHER_CRED_NAME', passwordVariable: 'OTHER_CRED_PASSWORD')
])
```